# Is 'It all happened so sudden' correct?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Can I say "It all happened so sudden"? I wanted to use it as a Whatsapp status but I am not entirely sure if I can use it like this.

Answer (score 1):

The word category [flat adverbs](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/flatadverbterm.htm) covers words that can be used adjectivally (to modify a noun) and adverbially (to modify a verb) without changing the form of the word. So, for example,...

> *Come quick!*
>    *Don't talk so loud.*
>    *Drop the gun real slow!*

...where we<sup>1</sup> might have expected *quickly, loudly, really slowly*.

OP's example probably wouldn't be explicitly identified as a credible "flaqt adverb" by any recognised authorities. The usage [does occur](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22happened%20so%20sudden%22), but there are ten times more instances of the "correct" version [*happened so **suddenly***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22happened%20so%20sudden%22#tbm=bks&q=%22happened%20so%20suddenly%22), and personally I don't think there's any reason for supposing that using the "incorrect" version would make native speakers think you've got an ear for relaxed colloquial speech patterns.

---

TL;DR: In essence, it's a mistake. But not a serious one, and it wouldn't normally be explicitly recognised as an error in ordinary speech. Except by pedants (and perhaps TEFL exam setters! :)

---

<sup>1</sup> By "we", I really mean "you" (learners), of course. Native speakers learn how to use flat adverbs by repeated exposure to examples which they then repeat in their own speech. Learners are much more likely to think in terms of applying a "rule" they've been taught (adjective + ***-ly*** = adverb).

Comment: I disagree. Sometimes quick for quickly is ok, but sudden instead of suddenly sounds uneducated. That is not a judgement. It's just a fact. If I hear a journalist say it, it is objectionable. If I hear it at Walmart, it's fine.

Comment: @Lambie "Uneducated" is a stretch.  It's informal, sure, but usages like this are quite common in speech.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm educated, but I'm quite capable of coming out with OP's usage even when I'm not in Asda (the UK version of Walmart). Would you have the same qualms about [*It all happened so **quick***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22happened+so+quick%22)? Personally I find that one even less "questionable", but whereas it's 10:1 for ***suddenly:sudden***, it's 15:1 for ***quickly:quick*** after *[It all] happened so...*

Comment: In certain circles (not defined **by me**), it happened so sudden would be unacceptable. So quick has passed into colloquial speech.